# Quick release lever free spinning

Tags: mountain-bike, repair

I have a Stance 2020 27.5 MTB with Rockshox Recon front axle. My quick release lever will free spin when I try to lock in the front wheel.

I have "fixed" it enough by tightening the screw, this allows me to lock on the wheel by first screwing the axle in. followed by tightening the lever independently. - essentially locking them in separately.

I can now MTB but there is a horrible clicking, and my fear is that I'm ruining something.

Is there a better fix I can do ?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  You might be able to get a better answer if you posted some pictures.

Comment: Can you clarify what type of front axle you have? Rockshox Maxle? adding a photo of it will help if you don't know.

Comment: Stop riding the bike.  Add a clear photo or two to this question using [edit]  Something is wrong here and yes you probably are risking damage by riding.

Answer (score 1):

Stop riding the bike until you know what's going on here. If you aren't able to work out what the issue is then find a mechanic who can look at it for you, losing the front wheel while riding is going to end up very badly for you.

That fork should have 15mm axle and you say it's a QR so usually you screw the axle in and to then flip the QR like lever up to lock it. There is often a small screw that adjusts the tension needed to lock the lever so it may just be that that needs adjusting.  But if you're in any doubt as to the security of the wheel don't ride the bike until it's sorted.

Comment: Agreed - sounds to me like someone's put a QR skewer in a through-axle hole, OR fitted a QR-based front wheel to a bike frame intended for a through axle, but is missing the adapters.

Answer (score 1):

With the standard quick release, the procedure is to install the wheel, flip the quick release lever to the "released" position, tighten the thumb nut on the opposite end of the quick release shaft until it just begins to get tight, then move the lever to the "locked" position.

If there is too much resistance, release the lever and unscrew the thumb nut a half turn or so.  If there is too little resistance, release the lever and screw in the thumb nut a half turn.